# How can I write a sample console application with Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I write a sample console application with Zend?

```
/Zend/Console/Getopt.php
```

I just want to pass a value as `-v` and will get the version information.

Input as

```
prjectfolder/console/version.php -v
```

Output:

```
Version 1.xxxxx
```

How can I code this in Zend with simple PHP with send lib includes methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a small example of how I am handling the CLI Interface for an Application. It is including my Bootstrap and the Zend Autoloader. A better solution is to change the Bootstrap for CLI Operations (no need for Dispatching and such stuff) but I am a lazy guy :-)

```
<?php
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/'));
define('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

/**
 * Setup for includes
 */
set_include_path(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../application/models' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../application/extends'. PATH_SEPARATOR .
    get_include_path());


/**
 * Zend Autoloader
 */
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

/**
 * Register my Namespaces for the Autoloader
 */
$autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');
$autoloader->registerNamespace('Db_');


/**
 * Include my complete Bootstrap
 * @todo change when time is left
 */
require '../application/bootstrap.php';

/**
 * Setup the CLI Commands
 * ../application/cli.php --add
 * ../application/cli.php --scan
 * ..
 */
try {
    $opts = new Zend_Console_Getopt(
        array(
            'help'      => 'Displays usage information.',
            'add'       => 'Add the Feeds to the Pipe',
            'scan'      => 'Scan the Feeds in the Pipe',
            'que'       => 'Process the Pipe',
        )
    );

    $opts->parse();

} catch (Zend_Console_Getopt_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage() ."\n\n". $e->getUsageMessage());
}

if(isset($opts->help)) {
    echo $opts->getUsageMessage();
    exit;
}

/**
 * Action : add
 */
if(isset($opts->add)) {
    // do something
}

/**
 * Action : scan
 */
if(isset($opts->scan)) {
    // do something
}

/**
 * Action : que
 */
if(isset($opts->que)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Symfony Console Component instead http://dev.umpirsky.com/building-cli-apps-with-symfony-console-component/

Answer (score -1):

You can find all the details you need in [ZF docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.console.getopt.html).

Comment: am new in Zend technology. so don't know how to use . console.